# I have to take extra input while using getline

Tags: c++, cin, cout, getline

I have to take extra input but i have not written in the code.
The code is

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int tc;
    scanf("%d ", &tc);
    while (tc--) {
        string treeString;
        getline(cin, treeString);
        int n1, n2;
        scanf("%d %d ", &n1, &n2);
        cout << n1 << " " << n2<< "\n";
        cout << treeString << endl;     
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting problems with the input and output operation. I have to add one extra input for the output.
I have inputted like this

```
2
aditya
4 5
```

after this I am expecting the result to be:

```
4 5
aditya
```

But I have to take extra input after taking 4 5 as the input (like this):

```
2 
aditya
4
5
6
```

why I have to take 6 as extra input? also I am unable to run at multiple test cases and here is the screenshot of that
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8faB.png)

Comment: Don't mix C and C++ input. Replace `scanf` calls with `std::cin >> tc;` and `std::cin >> n1 >> n2;`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, after replacing scanf with std::cin and adding cin.ignore() after, Everythings works fine. Can you please elaborate on why it does not work with scanf because I do coding on geeksforgeeks and there I cannot replace scanf with cin because there I can only code function other than main()

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, and I'm too lazy to figure it out. I suspect it might have something to do with trailing spaces in your `scanf` format strings.

Comment: I don't understand. You can use `getline(cin, some_string)` but you can't use `cin >> some_int`? That doesn't make any sense. What does `main` have to do with this?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I have used for taking whole string on a line as an input but cin >> some_string can only take one word at a time

Comment: I understand that. What I don't understand is how it's possible that the environment you are coding it allows you to use `getline` for strings, but somehow doesn't allow you to use `cin >> number` for ints and forces you to use `scanf` instead. What exactly doesn't work when you do try to use `cin >> number` in that environment of yours?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, Yes but some functions are running without problems. I am sharing two codes for doing the same thing: code 1 [link](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/6S8MSJ2wRA) this code run without problem but this code gives segmentation fault when using `scanf` but run correctly when using `cin` in the main function. the code is [link](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/KRLFFCSXJv).I am unable to understand the fault. In both code only change are in the function after driver codes ends.